# What's the effect of pentagram?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac

I am trying to understand the effect of each power-up, but for some of them is not easy.

What about the pentagram, for example? What is its effect, apart those nice devil's horns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Pentagram item **increases your damage by 3**.

[Source](http://bindingofisaac.wikia.com/wiki/Items) (Note that this wiki also features a lot of info on other items as well.)

Comment: Each single additional damage should be represented by a bar (visible when you press esc)?

Comment: @Drake Correct.